# In ReactMarkdown, how can I handle custom tags e.g. {{car:audi:q7}}

Tags: reactjs, react-markdown

How can I support custom tags in ReactMarkdown that starts with `{{` and ends with `}}`

e.g.

`This is my favorite car {{cars:audi:q7}} this year.`

to

`This is my favorite car <a href="mysite.com/cars?make=audi&model=q7>some text</a> this year.`

I've looked at renderers and custom components but none addresses custom tags

Comment: You have to create your own remark plugin

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating your own remark plugin unless there already exists one that does what you want.

You can start by reading the official documentation here: [Create Plugins](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/blob/main/doc/plugins.md#create-plugins). They also have tons of plugins to satisfy your needs.